# Down arrow key of my laptop?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, api

The down arrow key of my laptop is very loose and it does not seems to last very long.

Is it possible to write any programm(in any language but especially C++) hat simulates the down arrow key.say I made a programm such that when I press A,B,C on the key board it simulates down arrow key.

If not then,
Is there any software available to do this?

Comment: This question is broad in scope and unlikely to help many other programmers.

Comment: It's possible on any system. How I don't know. Try to see the source of autoclickers and keyloggers and connect it.

Comment: +1this kind of stuff could be useful if it works.thanks

Comment: Just FYI - you can probably buy a new keyboard for your laptop. They are easy to replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to simulate input, use the [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) API. This injects input at a fairly low level, windows automatically routes it to the appropriate thread based on who has focus. Call it twice, once to send the key down, and again to send the key up.

Perhaps the easiest thing to do is to write a simple app that calls RegisterHotkey for some combination like ctrl-alt-Z, and then calls SendInput for a keypress then keyrelease of the down arrow key.

You might need to wait a short time after receiving WM_HOTKEY to give you time to release the set of hotkeys so that the down arrow gets processed alone without those modifiers from your hotkey interfering with it. (...otherwise the focused app might think you typed in shift+alt+downarrow instead of plain downarrow!)

Comment: Well, I don't know which answer to pick but this seems more promising so far.Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use the [On-screen keyboard](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Type-without-using-the-keyboard-On-Screen-Keyboard)

Comment: Great! Now my left mouse key is buggered :-) But +1, since it _is_ useful.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using linux, xmodmap: http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xmodmap.1.html

Comment: perhaps,this is something ineresting+1

Comment: The tag specifically says **Windows**. It's OK to leave the answer for completeness though.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are actually looking for Sharpkeys [www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/)

This works with the windows registry and can be used to change mappings of keys.

Comment: hmm..I need to look into it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write a program that sends [`WM_KEYDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`WM_KEYUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages to the window which has the current focus. Once you have this program, bind it to a function key in the properties for the .exe file.

Comment: is it in C++ combined with windows shell scripting to do this.I have never done this before so I am going to try it.so just needed some guidance.where to start

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't want to send these to an app; it will bypass a lot of the input processing that windows does, so may work in some cases, but fail mysteriously in others. SendInput is the way to go here; it injects input at a low level, and Windows treats it pretty much exactly the same as a physical keystroke. (eg. these events are posted to a threads input queue, so an app could be processing them in its message loop: if you send these directly to a window, you bypass that.)